# How implements the public key of google play store in the free and premium key app

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play

I created an Android app that is free and has some sections that I want to unlock premium through a payroll application that makes unlocking key.

More or less clear to me that the way to do this is via `PackageManager`. Unclear but seeing several examples more or less yes.

Now the problem is that I'm trying to get my applications can not be hacked and include RSA public key that gives me Play Store. The problem is that I am unclear how to do it, since the examples I see lian me more than help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not in app purchase?

Comment: I do not want to have the free app payment options from it. It's a matter of marketing and advertising.